# Sum of Array with filter and reduce

Tags: angular

i'm trying to get the total of all my products in my list.

```
this.totalValue = this.items.filter((item) => item.qtyvalue)
                            .map((item) => item.qtyvalue)
                            .reduce((sum, current) => sum + current)
```

This is almost working as it gives me 650.00110.0030175.0050.00

But i want the numbers added together, how do i do this?

kind regards

Comment: Try this `this.totalValue = this.items.reduce((sum, item) => sum + +item.qtyvalue, 0)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's looks like your quantity is string not a number.You can try following code snippet

```
this.totalValue = this.items.filter((item) =>item.qtyvalue)
                            .map((item) => +item.qtyvalue)
                            .reduce((sum, current) => sum + current);
console.log(this.totalValue);
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsbin.com/lijetoyoku/edit?html,js,console,output)**

Comment: The little + sign before item.qtyvalue made the whole thing work... i though i had tried every thing. Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

I think, your `qtyvalue`-s are *strings*, not *numbers*, so you get just them concatenated as *strings*. In the `map` function use `parseFloat`.

```
this.totalValue = this.items.filter(item => item.qtyvalue)
                            .map(item => parseFloat(item.qtyvalue))
                            .reduce((sum, current) => sum + current)
```